# total transcations of a user in a given year

Tags: sql

I have two tables namely student and trans. In trans table, I have two column (transid,ide). In student table, I have three columns (id,name,gender).  The first two character of transid represent the year it take place for example (18000391)->2018,(19008978)->2019.Table trans is like:

```
trans_id|ide
190000678|1
200000453|2
180089376|1
190904988|2
183867647|1
```

table students is having value like:

```
id|name|gender
1|John|M
2|Mary|F
```

I want to calculate total number of transaction by particular person in given year. sample output should be in this form in which columns are (name,2018,2019,2020).

```
name|2018|2019|2020
John|2|1|0
Mary|0|1|1
```

My solution is like:

```
 WITH transcations AS (
 SELECT 
 f.('20')||(SUBSTR(trans_id),1,2),
 f.ide,
 g.id,
 g.name,
 g.gender
 FROM 
 db.trans f 
   INNER JOIN db.students g
   ON f.ide = g.id 
 )
 SELECT *
 FROM transcations 
 PIVOT(MAX(ID) FOR CATEGORY IN (2018, 2019, 2020) ) P
 GROUP BY ID;
```

PLEASE FIND SAMPLE CREATE TABLE QUERY AND INSERT INTO BELOW:

```
-- create a table
CREATE TABLE students (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name TEXT NOT NULL,
gender TEXT NOT NULL
 );

CREATE TABLE trans (
 trans_id INTEGER,
 ide INTEGER FOREIGN KEY
 );




  -- insert some values
  INSERT INTO trans VALUES (1800034,1);
  INSERT INTO trans VALUES (2000012,2);
  INSERT INTO trans VALUES (1900092,1);
  INSERT INTO trans VALUES (2000000,1);
  INSERT INTO trans VALUES (1800904,1);
  -- insert some values

  INSERT INTO students VALUES (1,'John','M');
  INSERT INTO students VALUES (2,'Mary','F');
```

Can someone help me in this question. How to approach this problem.

Comment: Please tag *only* the database you are using. MySql <> Sql Server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select s.name,
       sum(case when cast(trans_id as varchar(255)) like '18%'  then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2018,
       sum(case when cast(trans_id as varchar(255)) like '19%'  then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2019,
       sum(case when cast(trans_id as varchar(255)) like '20%'  then 1 else 0 end) as cnt_2020
from students s join
     trans t
     on t.ide = s.id
group by s.id, s.name
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But it is giving 0 for both students in 2018,2019,2020.

Comment: Try adjusting the LIKE patterns: `LIKE '18%'`, etc.